# ant build java program could not find targets

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am maintaining a java program that is not mine. I used eclipse and I could build the program with Ant. I don't know very much about Ant. Everything was installed fine on my eclipse IDE and the build worked perfect till today. I didn't change anything, so I don't know why it doesn't work anymore.

When I look at the external Tools Configurations,I see that the targets are missing. I have the message "No targets could be determined for the build file". Previously I could select some targets. Does someone know how it come that the targets disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by switching the eclipse workspace. I went to menu File->Switch Workspace->Other, and then I have selected the same workspace I was working with. Eclipse restarted and the error wasn't there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This helped for me:
remove the build file from Ant view and add it again.